# Core SignalR message sizes - is there a way to log how large your messages are?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I've read through the documentation and it seems like there is no built in way to measure the size of messages going out/coming in through SignalR. I have a very large amount of messages being sent out, and bandwidth can become an issue.

What I want to be able to do is run the SignalR server for a day and see how much data is transferred in total.

Does anyone know of a workaround to log this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can get message size in the debug level logging. Here is how you add that for anyone who might have the same issue.

```
Connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(Url, options =>
        {
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(tokenString);
        })
        .AddMessagePackProtocol()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            // Log to the Console
            logging.AddConsole();

            // Set to debug or trace
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace); 
        })
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
```