# SignalR message sizes - how to know how large your messages are?

Tags: c#, signalr, size

I'm new to SignalR, and I'm trying to find a way to discover and print, client side, the size of the received message.

```
    orderHubConnection.On<OrdersViewModel>(Message.OrdersUpdate.Value, model =>
    {
        // How to obtain size of "model" here?

        HandleOrdersUpdate(model);
    });
```

When I work with Web API, I can access to the ContentLength like this

```
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                OrdersModel = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OrdersViewModel>();
                OrdersModelSize = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
            }
```

but in SignalR the message I receive is already deserialized, and it's hard to find the size of the received content.

Anyone experienced the same need? Following link asks pretty much the same question

[Core SignalR message sizes - is there a way to log how large your messages are?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70357604/19101866)

Thanks!